# Linq Expressions and "Not Contains" query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

If I have linq which looks like this:
`!new List<int>{1,2,3}.Contains(x.someColumn)`

And I want to translate this to Expression, so something like this:

```
var mInfo = typeof (List<int>).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] {typeof (int)});
var lst = new List<int>();

foreach (var a in f.Value.Split(','))
{
    var b = int.Parse(a);
    lst.Add(b);
}

var lConst = Expression.Constant(iList);

var b = Expression.Call(lConst,mInfo, propertyReference);

return Expression.Lambda<Func<TmpResult, bool>>(b, param);
```

This will work like `Contains`, but how to change it to be like `!Contains`?

If I try to wrap it with `Expression.Not` I got error:

`The unary operator Not is not defined for the type System.Func`

Comment: Wrap the *body* `b` in `Expression.Not`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [**`Expression.Not`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299047(v=vs.110).aspx) method over the **body of the lambda expression**:

```
return Expression.Lambda<Func<TmpResult, bool>>(Expression.Not(b), param);
//                                              ^ negate body
```

Since a lambda-expression is a function, you **can not negate the lambda expression itself**, you can only **negate the result of the lambda expression**.